# How do I get the data from the user?

Tags: python, flask, post, web-applications

I am developing my first web application in Flask. The Accessing Request Data section of the official Quickstart explains how to handle a POST request. But it doesn't explain how to make it send me a POST request with data when a user fills out a form. I can send such a request to the right endpoint with a curl command and the application will work correctly. But I don't understand how to make a POST request to be sent when the user fills the form.

Comment: The Flask tutorial has everything you need to know. See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/tutorial/ // Second, sending a POST request from an HTML page is something that is independent of Flask. You'd want to look into how to use web forms. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms

Comment: maybe `flask` not describe this detail because it needs to know `HTML` - and it can assume that you already know `HTML`. So first learn `HTML` and `CSS` (and eventually `JavaScript`) and later try to use `flask` or any other web framework.

Answer (score 0):

You need specify it in your html: < form method="post">